# How to detect when a UIActionSheet scrolls to the bottom?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiactionsheet

I'm using the following method to detect when my table view scrolls to the bottom to add more table cells to the table view. how would I do the same for an `UIActionSheet`? I have the actionsheet populated with an `NSArray` with 40 rows, I would like to be able to scroll to the bottom and then add another 40 listings etc...

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

NSLog(@"scrollViewDidEndDecelerating");

float endScrolling = scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height;
if (endScrolling >= scrollView.contentSize.height)
{
    index ++;
    [self getFeed:index];
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: omg... why you not use Table-view..? action sheet is not for that purpose. You can customize table-view look with-setting images and other way look like action-sheet and also you can present table-view using Animation.

Comment: @NitinGohel I was having the UIActionSheet drop down after a user enters a search term. Doesn't it act like a tableView after a certain amount of items have been added as buttons? I'll post a screenshot to show what I mean.

Comment: Ypu can also drop down after a user enters a search term in UITableView by usins animation to show and hide.

Comment: Or also add your tableView on UIActionSheet as subView

Answer (score 2):

Maybe better use UIPickerView?